# An error occurred while calling o107.load

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc, teradata

I'm trying to connect to *Teradata*  using the following code:

```
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.repl.local.jars", f"{jar_location}//terajdbc4.jar")
conf.set("spark.executor.extraClassPath", f"{jar_location}//terajdbc4.jar")
conf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", f"{jar_location}//terajdbc4.jar")

driver = 'com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver'
url = "jdbc:teradata://{0}".format(hostname)

spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .config(conf=conf) \
        .appName(appName) \
        .master(master) \
        .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read \
        .format('jdbc') \
        .option('driver', driver) \
        .option('url', url) \
        .option('query', "Select * from {0}.".format(database) + srcTable) \
        .option('user', username) \
        .option('password', password) \
        .load()
print(df)
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o107.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 17.10.00.27] 
[Error 1536] [SQLState HY000] 
Invalid connection parameter name url
```

What does this error mean? and how to resolve it?

Comment: Spark classes pass Spark parameters along to the driver, in addition to the parameters the driver expects. By default, the driver throws an error when an unrecognized parameter name is included. Append the `/STRICT_NAMES=OFF` option to your URL to disable strict parameter checking and ignore the extra names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Fred is correct. Do this:

```py
url = "jdbc:teradata://{0}/STRICT_NAMES=OFF".format(hostname)
```